# Synonymous tags: bias-node and intercept?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [bias-node](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias-node) and [intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intercept) seems to me to be synonymous. [bias-node] is only used 6 times. Should we declare those as synonyms?

Comment: This is raised here since over a year: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2865/28666

Comment: That thread is largely being ignored by the mods but there are many good and well-upvoted merging suggestions there.

Comment: @amoeba +1 to your linked suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upvote two synonym suggestions here:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/intercept/synonyms

and also consider upvoting (or downvoting, as you see fit) as many pending synonym suggestions as you can:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

One needs to have >=5 rep in a master tag to vote. In order to vote, click on a master tag (left column) and vote via up/down arrows on the next page.

---

**Update:** Implemented.